# Griliches( dataset) from Ecdat not compatiable with current version of R

Tags: r

I have been using the dataset Griliches for a project. Tried going back to project and this error appears

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Griliches’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

A couple of weeks ago I updated all my packages, maybe this was the problem? I've tried deleting and downloading R again, also tried installing Griliches again.

I am new to R and finding this very confusing, also apologies if I didn't present my question properly.

Comment: I believe, that dataset is in `{Ecdat}`-package. Thus `install.packages("Ecdata")` followed by `data(Griliches, package = "Ecdat")` will yield Griliches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the data set 'Griliches'? This can be found from library [Ecdat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ecdat/index.html). Maybe you are confusing data and library with each other?

```
install.packages('Ecdat') 
library(Ecdat)
data('Griliches')
```

An alternative source for the same data is in [Github](https://rdrr.io/github/lachlandeer/hayashir/man/griliches.html). The Github version can be installed by:

```
install.packages('devtools') 
devtools::install_github('lachlandeer/hayashir')
library(hayashir) 
data(griliches)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I did get confuse data with Library.